# SD Card as storage (Not boot) drive

Tags: boot, sd-card, storage

I currently have my RPi3 booted from a usb flashdrive, I am wondering if it is possible to use an sd card as the mass storage option, without it being the boot drive. thanks!

-Dan

Comment: did you actually try anything before you posted your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You'll likely want to format the SD card to use a file system that's appropriate, then just make an /etc/fstab entry for it - just as you would any other drive.